# Mic positioning in 2 sitting actors scene

Tags: setup

I need a hint for some audio recording I have to do. 
I will be recording conversations between 2 people sitting at a table, as a sound operator in a shooting.
My question is: in this type of situation, is it good to just place a standing cardioid mic to pick up both voices, or should I follow the scene with a boom, trying to be always directed to the mouth of the one that's talking?

If anyone is experienced with that would be of good help.
Thankyou

Comment: This seems very opinion-based; per the [FAQ](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) "*your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?*” questions aren't generally on-topic for SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

It is more important for the mic to be close enough to the talent than it is for the mic to be pointed perfectly on-axis at the talent's mouth.  A cardiod 12" away that's 45 degrees off-axis will likely sound better than a cardiod 36" away that's dead-on.  Shotgun mics give you a bit more range, and a bit less tolerance for off-axis pickup.  But then again, the table may provide a very good early reflection that reinforces the actors voice and allows you to simply mic straight down with good results.

Depending on the size of the table, and where the actors' projection lines converge, you might be able to get away with a single mic aimed down between them, or you might effectively need two mics (either physically or by shuttling a single mic between them as they trade lines).

The key to successful sound recording is to know the principles of mic patterns and behaviors so that you can properly prepare for a session and successfully understand why you might be hearing what you hear when you actually put up the mics.  But that is only the starting point.  You must then always always always use your ears to adjust from what the principles predict to what actually works in the specific case with which you are dealing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to both, do both. I know more isn't necessarily always better but in this case it sounds like a simple shoot. Using both mics shouldn't get in the way.
That being said if you only have one option I'd say use the boom mic, especially if you have some sort of field recorder that gives you lot's of control. The nice thing about a boom mic is the freedom, even though it can be a pain in the ass. Also, depending on the quality of the boom mic you might be able to catch everything between the two individuals just pointing it at some central point. 
I hope I helped. Let me know if you have any other questions.